# ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error issue: Excel 64-bit/Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: excel, oracle

I'm running a VBA script I used to use when connecting to Oracle database through Excel 32-bit but now I'm using Excel 64-bit.

VBA code:

```vb
Set cn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
cn1.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=BR1P1;Uid=BR1USER;Pwd=myPass"
cn1.Open
rs1.Open Query, cn1
```

When I execute "cn1.open" I get this error:
`"Run-time error'-214746... [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"`

Then I tried to solve adding a new data source:
ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)> File DSN> click in Add...> from list I select: Oracle em OraClient11g_home1 ("Oracle em" means "Oracle for", my OS in in portuguese)> Next> browse to the file: "C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe"> Next> Finish

Doing so system will give me the driver name: `"Oracle em OracleClient11g_home1"`

Afterwards it will prompt for Service Name, User Name and Password. I inform server Name according to my TNSNAMES.ORA

Back to VBA I changed the code according to the driver name:

```vb
cn1.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle em OracleClient11g_home1}"
```

Now when execute "cn1.Open" in VBA I receive this new error message:

```
"Run-time error'-214746... [Oracle][ODBC]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error"
```

My TNSNAMES.ORA file is like this:

```
BR1P1 = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.com)(PORT = 1575))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = BR1P1)))
```

Well I'm just stucked on this. Please I appreciate any help on this.
It's being a pain after I changed my MS Office to 64-bit version.

Comment: Where did you store the `tnsnames.ora` file? Create an Environment Variable `TNS_ADMIN` pointing to this folder.

Comment: File is located in "C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin\". And I already created a variable named "TNS_ADMIN" pointing to this exact path. Anyway, I've found the solution.Basically for my connection string I changed

Comment: Sorry, see the full comment: File is located in "C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin\". And I already created a variable named "TNS_ADMIN" pointing to this exact path. Anyway, I've found the solution. Basically for my connection string I added DBQ, UID, and PWD like this: cn1.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle em OraClient11g_home1}; DBQ=BR1P1; PUID=myUser; Pwd=myPwd". And there is a main detail: I used "DBQ" word, not "Server" like I normally would. Not sure why but it worked.

Comment: Yes, the connection string format for [Microsoft ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/connection-string-format-and-attributes?view=sql-server-2017) is different to [Oracle ODBC Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183)

Comment: Great! thanks you so much Wernfried for the complete information regarding ConnectionString formats and off course all the help.

Answer (score 2):

The `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle` exist only for 32-bit thus you cannot use it for 64-bit Excel.

If you like to use the 64-bit ODBC driver from Oracle then you must install it. Download the driver from [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/tools/index-090165.html)

The ConnectionString format of the Oracle ODBC Driver is different to the format of the Microsoft ODBC driver, see

- [Microsoft ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/connection-string-format-and-attributes?view=sql-server-2017) - Connection String Format and Attributes
- [Oracle ODBC Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183) - Format of the Connection String
- or https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ -> ODBC drivers

So, for Oracle your ConnectionString

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=BR1P1;Uid=BR1USER;Pwd=myPass
```

will be

```
Driver={Oracle em OracleClient11g_home1};DBQ=BR1P1;Uid=BR1USER;Pwd=myPass
```

Comment: Well.. I understand that and I already installed 64-bit ODAC. I created a new data source to connect using ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) but it's no working. So my issue is to use 64-bit ODBC through VBA.